# Round leaves zeroes after

Tags: sql-server

In sql server I'm trying to truncate a number to 4 digits after the coma. From what I know I need to use Round(n, b, f). n should be the number I want to round, b is how many digits after the coma should be left and if f is 0 then it works like a normal Round but if it's not 0 then it should Truncate after the digits specified in b. But it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is the code

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(LAT_N), 4, 1)
FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N > 38.7880 AND LAT_N < 137.2345
```

It should sum all the lat_n that are bigger than 38.7880 and smaller than 137.2345 and truncate the sum to 4 digits. But it gives me this result: **36354.81350000** instead of **36354.8135**. I tried with CAST this way:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(SUM(LAT_N), 4) AS DECIMAL(8, 4)
FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N > 38.7880 AND LAT_N < 137.2345
```

But it didn't work giving me this error *Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.* I've had to do similar stuff before with only 2 decimals and Cast with Decimal(8, 2) used to work. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong with the Cast or maybe Round isn't what I need?

Comment: `ROUND` doesn't change the data type or precision and scale of a value, it just rounds it. This is well [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). The `decimal(8,4)` value `137.2345` `ROUND`ed to `0` decimal places is `137.0000` because it's still a `decimal(8,4)`; the value is still accurate to 4 decimal places. If you don't want decimal values, then convert/cart the value to a lower scale.

Comment: `ROUND` manipulates the value but does not [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) it for display. If you want to process the rounded value as a number use `ROUND`. If you want to display the value in a specific way, use `FORMAT` only. `FORMAT` converts the number to a string.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest `FORMAT`, @OlivierJacot-Descombes, is performs **terribly**.

Comment: Usually this kind of problem should be solved in the front-end UI anyway, e.g. by specifying a format in a data grid view. This is not a SQL problem.

Comment: Remember, the first number in the type specification is the *total* number of significant digits, the second is the number of those digits after the decimal. `36354.8135` has 9 significant digits. It literally, as the error says, cannot fit into a `decimal(**8**, 4)`.

Comment: @Larnu it is indeed well documented. And it does say that it can be used as a Truncate if I don't have 0 as the third input. But it doesn't work the way I though it would. I though truncating would remove the numbers, but instead it makes them to 0.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you very much. Such a silly mistake, but I didn't really know how to use the cast as decimal.

Comment: Why are you summing latitudes anyway?

Comment: For hackerrank, which is a website that gives you sql exercises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`36354.8135` won't fit in `decimal(8,4)`. If you want numbers > 9999 and you want four decimal places, you'll need more than 8 for precision.

Try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(20,4), 36354.8135);
```